# Angular App Hosting on S3+CloudFront: Handling 404 Errors

Tags: reactjs, angular, amazon-s3, devops, amazon-cloudfront

When I uploaded my Angular application on S3 combined with CloudFront, I encountered a 404 error when directly accessing a specific view. It happened because the view is a component that relies on `index.html` for rendering rather than being a standalone `.html` file. I configured an error page on the `S3 bucket` - it still redirects to index.html when encountering a `404 error`. As a result, specific routes like the path to my privacy policy generate a `404 error` before redirecting to index.html for rendering.

This keeps the user's experience but can confuse web crawlers and ad bots trying to check the validity of the links.

I tried using `CloudFront's` custom error page to return a misleading `200` response to crawlers. Still, this solution interferes with the user experience since I have two `S3` origins, each requiring its custom error page.

Comment: my initial solution would be to have a distribution for each origin so i can apply the custom error page in cloudfront on each one, but then they need to be firstly detached because they depend on each other. so i am still looking for a way to fix this before i try and detach them